# Did Adam really commit a sin?

Tags: tafseer, prophets, belief

In verse 121 of Surah 20 we read:

> **وعصی آدم ربه  فغوی**
>
> **َAdam disobeyed his Lord and went amiss**

Did Adam really commit a sin? Isn't it impossible for a Prophet to commit a sin? Isn't it right that a Prophet must be infallible?

Comment: Infallible does not mean free from sin but forgiven

Comment: Dear amrinz, vice versa, infallible of being Ma'soom as 14 infallibles (Ma'sooms) (of Shia) were infallible , which means do not sin ...

Answer (score 2):

At other place Allah describes Adam's position as :

> وَلَقَدْ عَهِدْنَآ إِلَى ءَادَمَ مِن قَبْلُ فَنَسِىَ وَلَمْ نَجِدْ
>   لَهُ عَزْماً
>
> (And indeed We made a covenant with Adam before, but he forgot, and We
>   found on his part no firm willpower) --"Qur'an 20:115"

So, it was not something which Adam was determined to do, it was just a mistake, a forgetfulness. I think that clears the issue.